Does P=BPP implies we can construct a Boolean circuit for a fair coin flip?
I would precisely like to know if the conjecture BPP=P implies the following:

Is it possible to build a classical Boolean circuit whose outputs are statistically indistinguishable from a fair coin flip? No random bits are given as input to the circuit.

As usual, the circuit shall contain Gates from a universal gate set (say, NAND gate only). There should not be any other hidden (computational) resources.

Adding a context a bit: The question occurred to me while I am searching for a circuit for a related question as below:
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/38576/21801

Please define the problem more clearly.  What does "similar" mean?  Do you mean that the outputs are indistinguishable from random in some sense?  If so, what sense do you have in mind?  What are the inputs to the Boolean circuit?  If it is a randomized circuit, i.e., its inputs include some random bits, then obviously such a thing can be built.  You say "precisely" but the question isn't very precise yet.

@D.W., I have edited it to clarify the input to the circuit and statistical test for randomness. It is acceptable if any suitable measure for statistical indistinguishability is taken. Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests or so.

If the circuit is deterministic, how do you expect for the output to look random? With the same inputs, it will get the same outputs.

@Nathaniel, I am taking your point. // By the way it all started while I was searching for the answer of a related question as below. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/38576/21801

No, it's impossible regardless of what conjectures you might make.  A deterministic circuit will always produce the same thing, when given the same inputs.  A random coin flip won't.  Those are trivially distinguishable.
